# Firebase notification not working on Android VIRTUAL devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app that use Firebase Cloud Messagging and have a strange issue with a push notifications sent by a remote server through FCM.

The strange behavior i'm talking about is that everything is working like a charm when i run my app in my usb-attached phone Oneplus2 (Android 6.0.1, API 23). But running in a Virtual device (i tried to create many of them, with different API version and Android version) seem not even to be executed the **onMessageReceived** function of **FirebaseMessagingService**.

I suspected a not good configuration in the virtual device created from AVD Manager, but according to Firebase documentation i need

> - A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and    Google Play services 10.2.0 or higher
> - The Google Play services SDK from the Google Repository, available in the Android SDK Manager
> - The latest version of Android Studio, version 1.5 or higher

and i'm ok with these three requisites.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

FirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        Log.i("PVL", "MESSAGE RECEIVED!!");
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, WalkersMain.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Walkers")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ctscts.game"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme"
        >

        <activity
            android:name="com.ctscts.game.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*Note*: i tried to send the request both from Firebase Console and my remote server, with the same behaviour.

How do i perform the send request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/send" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sentNotification(@RequestBody String body, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String serverKey = "AAAAfZXBxHk:APA91bFlZ6ty7DQbLZkF5LJJUQJbYlO6JuJ8JmcQetG_cyAYD69QvPT6KK3KWkfTWHEWfgrwg7C7GSS1rWlNcumNNmkWfVae5p89";

        List<User> lista = userService.findAllUsers();

        List<String> listaToken = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (User user : lista) {
            listaToken.add(user.getToken());
        }

        Sender sender = new FCMSender(serverKey);
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("message")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", "Notification from Java application")
                .build();

        MulticastResult result;
        try {
            result = sender.send(message, listaToken, 1);
            System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

In debug mode, when i execute the line result = sender.send(message, listaToken, 1); the value of *message* variable is

```
Message(collapseKey=message,
    timeToLive=3,
    delayWhileIdle=true,
    data: {
        message=Notification from Java application
    }
)
```

and listaToken contains the list of tokens to reach. 
Here the result:

Result:

```
MulticastResult(multicast_id=9084949851503613851,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1489049633129649%6a8d477338eb0007 ]]
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/avds

Comment: ehi @sanketpahuja, thank you! :-)

Comment: any suggestion??

Comment: It's a bit hard for us to comment on anything. You are sure that the problem is with the emulator, but then you say that it complies accordingly. Can you post some code snippets (`onMessageReceived()`) and a sample payload? From where are you sending the payload? The more relevant details you can post, the better. :)

Comment: yes @AL i'm adding a Edit

Comment: @AL. how can i extrapolate the payload to post here? Any hint?

Comment: Just post the sample payload as text.

Comment: @AL. look at the last Edit, i tried to find the payload somehow. Does it helps?

Comment: Okay, cool. Code looks fine. Have you tested this in multiple emulators (with different specs)? Are you positive that you're using the correct registration token for the emulator?

Comment: I tested in avds with different API versions and Android version..
My function takes every registered token and send to each the notification. So i'm pretty sure that the token is correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution.
According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server):

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
>   from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
>   FCM in order for your Firebase Cloud Messaging client apps to receive
>   messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. FCM typically
>   only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. FCM doesn't
>   provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept
>   outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks
>   listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

My company firewall was blocking network traffic on those ports, so i tried to use a VPN service with no network restrictions and everything worked.